# Java/JUnit Filtering Repeated Conditions

Tags: java, junit

My specific question is with regards to JUnit's [Parameterized Tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests), filtering (essentially not running) tests if it contains a certain property. For example:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    if (property.contains("example")) {
        return;
    }
    assertEquals(expected, methodToTest1(actual));
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    if (property.contains("example")) {
        return;
    }
    assertEquals(expected, methodToTest2(actual));
}
```

The question is, does a technique exist where the constraint `if (property.equals("example"))...` be defined somewhere else statically, instead of before each and every test method? Like this:

```
/** define constraint "property.equals("example")" somewhere **/

@Test
public void test1() {
    assertEquals(expected, methodToTest1(actual));
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    assertEquals(expected, methodToTest2(actual));
}
```

Comment: Do you want just run the test if the propery.equals("example")?

Comment: Only run `if !(property.contains("example"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use JUnit's [Assume feature](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assumptions-with-assume) together with `@Before`.

Add an `@Before` method to your test class

```
@Before
public void dontRunIfExample() {
  assumeFalse(property.contains("example"));
}
```

and remove the `if` block from each of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are running your JUnit tests. You can quite literally use Java's `System.getProperty("conditionForTest")`. Then if you are launching them by command line you will need to specify them with `-DconditionForTest=true` or if you are running the tests with ant then it can be passed into the an target.

```
<sysproperty key="conditionForTest" value="true"/>
```